# Putting all distinct pages in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is that how professionals do it? All the content in one file, I need to do a school project; I can use javascript to hide and show the content. For ex. I am having an about and contact page so using javascript I'll switch through it (display block and none) but I want the transition to have an animation specifically slide, so how will I do it?

Comment: Learn about Single-Page Applications, and frameworks like React or Durandal.

Comment: you have to use styling with values display none and block don't have animations

Comment: @isherwood I was in a hurry so jumbled up my english, my bad...

Comment: @RudiUrbanek I am asking how to do it because I dont know how to do it.. so if you could give me an example, just to help me get an A

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here an example everything that has values can be animatet

```css
.animation {
  position: relative;
  display: initial;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.animation:after {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.fail:after {
  display: none;
}
.fail:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
.success:after {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  display: block;
}
.success:hover:after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="animation fail">Failing to animate</div>

<div class="animation success">Animatet</div>
```